# Can't make requests in mern stack heroku hosted application, in production version

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, cookies, mern

i make a social media in mern stack, and all is fine in development. But in production, i have a problem with my requests.

To explain better, first my problem was a cookie issue, i need a cookie to have the user logged in, and at first, the request was ok (code 200) but i haden't the cookie, and the user wasn't connected.
And now, after some changes to set the cookie, the request is not ok (error 400), it seems like the front don't communicate with the back. I don't see where can be my mistakes.

My app is hosted on heroku (back and front sides), and i buy a domain name, who is https://www.universegram.fr

I put below my development code, and after the changes i make for the production.

## Development Code

### Server.js

```js
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

const corsOptions = {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
    "allowedHeaders": ["sessionId", "Content-Type"],
    "exposedHeaders": ["sessionId"],
    "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    "preflightContinue": false
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.set("trust proxy", 1);
// Read bodys and cookies on our requests
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// jwt middleware
app.get("*", checkUser);
app.get("/jwtid", requireAuth, (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send(res.locals.user._id)
});

// Routes
app.use("/api/user", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/post", PostRoutes);

// Server static assets if in production
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"){
    // Set static folder
    app.use(express.static("client/build"))

    app.get("*", (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"))
    })

}

// Server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on ${process.env.PORT
        }`);
})
```

### AuthController.js (SignIn method)

```js
module.exports.signIn = async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    try {
        const user = await UserModel.login(email, password);
        const token = createToken(user._id);
        res.cookie("jwt", token, {
            maxAge: maxAge, 
            sameSite: "lax",
            // httpOnly: true,
            secure: false,
        })
        res.status(200).json({ user: user._id })

    }
    catch (err) {
        const errors = signInErrors(err);
        res.status(400).json({ errors });
        // console.log(err)
    }
}
```

### My package.json (Client side)

```json
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "firebase": "^9.7.0",
    "hamburger-react": "^2.5.0",
    "particlesjs": "^2.2.3",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-burger-menu": "^3.0.6",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.50.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "craco eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.8",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "reactjs-popup": "^2.0.5",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1"
  }
}
```

## Production changes

(Change origin)

```js
const corsOptions = {
    origin: "https://www.universegram.fr",
    credentials: true,
    "allowedHeaders": ["sessionId", "Content-Type"],
    "exposedHeaders": ["sessionId"],
    "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    "preflightContinue": false
}
```

(Change cookie settings)

```js
module.exports.signIn = async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    try {
        const user = await UserModel.login(email, password);
        const token = createToken(user._id);
        res.cookie("jwt", token, {
            maxAge: maxAge, 
            sameSite: "none",
            // httpOnly: true,
            secure: true,
        })
        res.status(200).json({ user: user._id })

    }
    catch (err) {
        const errors = signInErrors(err);
        res.status(400).json({ errors });
        // console.log(err)
    }
}
```

I try a lot of things but util now i don't find the good solution..Thanks in advance if you can help me

Comment: I tried to login in your website. Front communicating with back correctly. You need check what body come from frontend in your `AuthController.js`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i take a look and from my front-end, from my request, nothing, it come directly in the catch method. Here is my SignIn component:

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, i take a look and from my front-end, from my request, nothing, it come directly in the catch method. Here is my SignIn component:

```js
const SignInForm = () => {

    const { uid, setUid } = useContext(UidContext);

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    // States to take the inputs values
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");


    // console.log(uid)
    // Function to login the user or display the errors
    const handleLogin = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const emailError = document.querySelector(".email.error");
        const passwordError = document.querySelector(".password.error");

        axios({
            method: "post",
            url: `/api/user/login`,
            withCredentials: true,
            data: {
                email,
                password
            }
        })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res)
                if (res.data.errors) {
                    emailError.innerHTML = res.data.errors.email;
                    passwordError.innerHTML = res.data.errors.password;
                } 
                else {
                    dispatch(getUser(res.data.user))
                        .then(() => dispatch(getUsers()))
                        .then(() => setUid(res.data.user))
                        .then(() => navigate("/home"))
                }
                // navigate("/home")

            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err + "C'est chelou");
            })
    }

    return (
        <form action="" onSubmit={handleLogin} id="sign-up-form" >
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text"
                name="email"
                id="email"
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                value={email} />
            <div className="email error"></div>
            <br />

            <label htmlFor="password">Mot de passe</label>
            <input type="password"
                name="password"
                id="password"
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                value={password} />
            <div className="password error"></div>
            <br />

            <input type="submit" value="Se connecter" />
        </form>
    )
}
```